# conectar Ajax con backend-SpringBoot

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, backend

Buen dia a todos, tengo un problema con la siguiente función la cual por medio de Ajax hago una consulta a mi backend(SpringBoot) enviandole un "id" para validar si existe ese registro, pero la respuesta que recibo siempre es por mi request.fail, y solo muestra el emnsaje del alert("Request failed:error").

```
function consulta(){        
    var id=parseInt(document.getElementById("n1").value)
    alert("codigo a consultar: "+id)            
    var request=$.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:5000/productos/existe",
        type : "GET",
        data : {
            "id":id
        },
        //processData: false,
        //contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        timeout: 600000,
        dataType: "json",
    });
    request.done(function(data) 
    {
        alert("prueba en el done");
        $("#rta").text(data);            
    });             
    request.fail(function( e,textStatus ) 
    {
        alert( "Request failed: " +textStatus );
        $("#rta").text(textStatus);
    }); 
    
}
```

Verifique en mi Backend  colocando mensajes en consola y el dato de consulta llega correctamente, la consulta se realiza  a la BDy muestra cuando se encuentra el registro y cuando no existe, tal como tengo los System.out.print("") en el backend.

```
@GetMapping(path="/existe")
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity validarExistencia(@RequestParam(value="id")long codigo) {
    System.out.println("Backend. codigo consultado es: "+codigo);
    ResponseEntity respuesta=null;
    if(servicio.consultarExistenciaProductoServicio(codigo)) {
        System.out.println("encontrado codigo");
        respuesta= new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("no existe codigo");
        respuesta= new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
    return respuesta;
}
```

Entonces aislando todo mi problema es que mi ajax no esta resiviendo mi ResponseEntity y la verdad de Ajax o javascript no se nada, ayuda porfa :(

Comment: Hola! El código se comparte como texto, no como imagen. No te van (vamos) a responder con imagenes para ponerte a transcribir. :)

Comment: oka, ya corregi eso :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

el problema parece ser debido a la estructura de tu backend parece ser que solicita la informacion mediante una solicitud tipo `POST`, para que sea tipo `GET` el url debe de contener parametros de la siguiente manera `/productos/existe?id=id_value`, hay dos formas de obtener el resultado que esperas, una forma es cambiar `GET` a `POST` en tu `$.ajax` (es la forma mas facil), sin el futuro deseas utilizar mas comodamente las solicitudes tipo GET, te recomiendo cambiar la estructura de tu API para que pueda leer parametros de la url, y ahi poder utilizar `$.getJSON` de jquery.

el codigo puede quedar de la siguiente manera

**NOTA** para que este codigo funcione asegurate de que tu codigo backend estas manejando la informacion como arreglo u objeto, dependiendo a como lo codifiques

```
function consulta(){  
    // creamos el objeto que vamos a mandar      
    var data = {
        id: $('#n1').val()
    }; 
    alert("codigo a consultar: "+id)            
    var request=$.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:5000/productos/existe",
        type : "POST",
        data : data,
        //processData: false,
        //contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        timeout: 600000,
        dataType: "json",
        encode: true,
    });
    request.done(function(data) 
    {
        alert("prueba en el done");
        $("#rta").text(data);            
    });             
    request.fail(function( e,textStatus ) 
    {
        alert( "Request failed: " +textStatus );
        $("#rta").text(textStatus);
    }); 
    
}
```